# I get java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB when i draw my canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw some points on my view using a canvas.
But as soon i try to  draw my canvas on my view with

```
 view.draw(canvas);
```

I get the error `java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB` and then my app crash immediately.
Does someone has an idea how i can reduce the size of my canvas or fix this error ?

Here is my current code :

```
onDrawListener = new OnDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLayerDrawn(Canvas canvas, float pageWidth, float pageHeight, int displayedPage) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("PdfViewer", "Drawing view");
                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                        canvas.drawPoint(canvas.getWidth() /2, canvas.getHeight() /2, paint);
                        view.draw(canvas); //here i get the error
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("PdfViewer", e.toString());
                    }


                }
            };
```

Thank you

Comment: It most likely means you have an eternal recursion. Are you sure your draw call doesn’t cause it calling itself? What’s the call stack at the moment of crash?

Answer (score 1):

The line you mentioned calls `view.draw(canvas);` This calls your `onDrawListener`, which calls `view.draw(canvas)`, which calls your `onDrawListener`, which calls `view.draw(canvas)`, and so on...

Every time a function calls another function, it passes data to the function it is calling through a "stack frame". This takes space in memory, and each stack frame gets freed when the function it is associated with returns. Since your `onDrawListener` calls itself, it will never return, and that memory will keep getting used, until there is none left.

Remove the line you highlighted, and, assuming no other issues are present, it should work.

Comment: When i remove the line i get no more errors,
But my nothing draw on my canvas, do you have any ideas why ?

Comment: I am not an expert in this graphics library, but based on naming conventions, I imagine onDrawListener is called whenever you call view.draw(canvas) . The code to draw the canvas should therefore be outside the listener, perhaps in an initialise method, unless this is code you want to happen "whenever something draws to the canvas"